# Fixing "This branch is X commits behind Y." through the GitHub web interface

Tags: github

After forking a GitHub repo, some commits were pushed to the forked repo, and as a result GitHub indicates that  "This branch is X commits behind Y.":

[image]

How can I fix it through the GitHub web interface?

---

I know how to do it through git: [GitHub keeps saying "This branch is X commits ahead, Y commits behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41289258/395857):

```
git remote add upstream https://github/upstream/repo.git
git pull --rebase upstream master
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```